# How do I use the AWS SDK for Javascript to make a POST request to a public API Gateway resource/method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I want to be able to post a json object using a particular URI made public by API Gateway. How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this example provided by AWS API Gateway to learn how to create an API to fit your use case. [Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-from-example.html)

Basically, you need to create an API, and a resource, then you need to create a POST method for your endpoint.